# how can I change the icon of Right side NavigationDrawer when I have 2 navigation drawers

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have 2 navigation drawers in my app. how can I change the icon of right side navigation drawer? all the links I saw was talking about one navigation drawer case and solved using ActionBarToggle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_viewLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_left" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_viewRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer_right" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: inside @layout/activity_main I have a toolbar.  I have below code too.              toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

Comment: yes. I have menu options on both drawers. but pls share your class. it might give some idea to me or others.

Comment: I do not want animation like hamburger menu. static icon is what I want

Comment: Ah, OK. That's much simpler. Something like what Sangeet has is what you want then. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can only show navigation icon on left side of the toolbar. The possible solution will be use menu to include navigation drawer icon from https://material.io/icons/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/search" android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
   />
<item
    android:id="@+id/btnMyMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
    android:title="Right Side Menu"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

On clicking btnMyMenu open drawer accordingly using

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

Then hide and show that menu accordingly

Comment: check this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myntra.android

Comment: This app is using menu item. On clicking menu item, drawer us open from right side

Comment: I had below menu for actionbar. right side icon was coming from below file. changed icon here and it worked.                                               <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="style.smash.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_grey"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>